# Add IBM Watson Knowledge Studio model id to IBM Discovery

Tags: curl, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I tried to add my Watson Knowledge Studio model id to my Watson Discovery configuration [as described here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/integrate-wks.shtml).

Downloading my config with this command works great:

```curl
curl -u "{username}":"{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/configurations/{configuration_id}?version=2016-12-01" > my_config.json
```

But when I just tried to upload this file without any changes with this command:

```curl
curl -X PUT -u "{username}":"{password}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -F configuration=@my_config.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/configurations/{configuration_id}?version=2016-12-01"
```

I will always get an:

```json
{
"code": 400,
"error": "Unexpected token -"
}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you validate the JSON file you're uploading as configuration? It may have an error in it.

Comment: there is no error, i validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some help from IBM, it seems that the documentaiton is wrong.
The correct command is

```
curl -X PUT -u "{username}":"{password}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d@my_config.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_ID}/configurations/{Configuration_ID}?version=2016-12-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree - the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/integrate-wks.shtml)  is wrong.
What worked for me:

1) delete the configuration Id from the edited my_config.json config file (since this is a default config)

2) insert a new configuration (and obtain a newly generated configuration Id > note there is no configuration id set in the request)

```
 curl -X POST -u {username}":"{password}"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d@my_config.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/configurations?version=2016-12-01"
```